# Drupal 8 MySQL database query

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I have a custom module with a defined path. I want to query a separate database (within the localhost) and pull this data through the response, so that that it shows up on the .twig page for the module.

I am working on a local dev environment on my laptop. Just can’t get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Controller.php file:

```
namespace Drupal\career_pathways\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class PathwaysController{
 public function getPaths(){
  $response = new Response();

   $con = \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection('career_pathways','default');
   $sql = query("SELECT * FROM {pathways}");
   $result = $query->execute();

   if ($result) {
     while ($row = $result->fetchAll()) {
       // Do something with:
       $response = array(
         '#theme' => 'career_pathways',
         '#title' => 'Career Pathways',
         '#markup' => 'A Career Without Boundaries',
         '#firstname' => $row['firstname'],
         '#lastname' => $row['lastname'],
         '#role' => $row['role'],
         '#company' => $row['company']
       );
     }
   }
return $response;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the support and help!

Comment: Whats the output you are getting. what result you get when`kint($result)`

Comment: Hi Razeem. Thanks in advance for any help you can offer. the only output i get on the screen is: The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Comment: @RazeemAhmad in addition, when i check the console->network, i get this: 500 500 Service unavailable (with message)

Comment: Many thanks for the help, although I’ve managed to finally figure out my solution to my problem. I will post it as an answer when I get some time. Hopefully it can help others in the future.

Answer (score 2):

To get your route displayed in a custom template file you need to do the following

**career_pathways.routing.yml**

```
career_pathways.getpaths:
  path: '/getpaths'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\career_pathways\Controller\PathwaysController::getPaths'
    _title: 'getPaths'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

**PathwaysController.php**

```
namespace Drupal\career_pathways\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class PathwaysController extends ControllerBase {
 public function getPaths(){
   $query = \Drupal::database()->query( "SELECT * FROM pathways" );
   $results = $query->fetchAll();
   $processedResults=[];
    :
   Process your result here
    :

   $build = [
     '#theme' => 'career_pathways',
      '#results' => $processedResults,
    ];
    return $build;
  }
}
```

**career_pathways.module**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function career_pathways_theme() {
  return [
    'career_pathways' => [
      'variables' => [
        'results' => NULL,
      ],
      'render element' => 'children',
    ],
  ];
}
```

**templates/career-pathways.html.twig**

```
Hi im working
{{results}}
```

Now, After getting your template loaded properly. Add your logic and pass it to the `$results` variable

Comment: I can get everything to show but the $results variables will not show up when i render the .twig file. Am i missing something?

Comment: Are you getting `Hi im working` rendered. And, have you cleared your caches after doing these

Comment: Yes i am clearing my caches and get 'hi i am working'. I have managed to get your code working, however when i do as you say and add my query logic to it, i still have the same problem of it not liking the query to mysql.

Comment: The problem seems to be around these lines of code: $sql = query("SELECT * FROM {pathways}");
$result = $query->execute();

Comment: Try this  `$query = \Drupal::database()->query(
        "SELECT * FROM pathways"
    );
    $result = $query->fetchAll();`

Comment: Right so, if i put the 'pathways' table into my 'drupal8' database i can get it working. However, i want the 'pathways' table to sit separately in a 'careerspaths' database - in the same local environment. This is where the problems are occurring for me.